# Embedded images are not showing in outlook

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, dns, iis-7.5, kentico

We have a site hosted in IIS 7.5 AWS server (Windows 2008 server), application is built using Kentico 9, and we use AWS SES as an email server.

We have an email sending function which embeds images. We use image tag in the body `<img src="http://...../...jpg" alt="" />` of the e-mails.

The issue is that the images are not showing in the Outlook client. However, it works nicely in web clients.

The images are stored in the same directory where the application is hosted. If we use an external image URL it works as expected.

We have tested and confirmed that this is not a Kentico issue but most probably a server related issue, maybe in IIS/Server/DNS/Network.

Answer (score 1):

For emails you will need to have the FQDN plus the image path.

You might also check out https://litmus.com/ also for proper email sending syntax.

Also check out https://backgrounds.cm/